# Export mysql table column as newline-separated values in text file

Tags: php, text, styles, newline, fwrite

I have this script to output into a text file:

```
$sql = "SELECT bodyipaddress from email_body";
$query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$cnt=1;
if($query->rowCount() > 0)
{
    foreach ($results as $result)   
    {
        $bodyipaddress       = $result->bodyipaddress;
        // create a txt file 

        $myfile      = fopen("file.txt", "a");
        $padded_text = str_pad($bodyipaddress, 0, '', STR_PAD_RIGHT);
        fwrite($myfile, $bodyipaddress);
        fclose($myfile);
                                        
        $cnt=$cnt+1; 
    }    
}
```

But the data's result when read through the text file was a plain text and the formatting has disappeared.
Was it possible for me to style the text vertically by using `p`

Below is the output that I want to change to vertically for each white spaces found.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your question by providing the data displayed from `var_export($dbh->query("SELECT bodyipaddress FROM email_body")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are exporting a columnar set of data from the entire `email_body` table, so the most elegant/direct approach IMO is:

1. Execute a standard pdo query -- since there are no parameters to bind values to, a prepared statement is needless overhead.
2. Form the result set into a flat array using `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN`.
3. Since it only makes sense to create or totally overwrite the file, I do not recommend the `a` mode on `fopen()` -- `w` seems more appropriate so that there will be no appended data.  In fact, you may even prefer to call `file_put_contents()` as a single function call versus `fopen()`, `fwrite()`, then `fclose()`.
4. Implode the flat array of ip addresses with `PHP_EOL` to align the newline sequence with your system environment (`\r\n` or `\n`).
5. You aren't using `$cnt` in your posted script, so that manually incremented tally can be completely omitted.  If you want to know how many ip addresses are in the array, just call `count()` on the result set array.
6. I don't understand why you are trying to right-pad your ip addresses with empty spaces to a length of zero characters.

New code:

```
file_put_contents(
    "file.txt",
    implode(
        PHP_EOL,
        $dbh->query("SELECT bodyipaddress FROM email_body")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN)
    )
);
```

...Yes, it actually is just that simple/concise.

---

If your `bodyipaddress` *actually* has comma&space-separated values, then you can replace them with new lines in the sql or in php.  I don't know what your table data really looks like.

```
file_put_contents(
    "file.txt",
    str_replace(
        ', ',
        PHP_EOL,
        implode(
            PHP_EOL,
            $dbh->query("SELECT bodyipaddress FROM email_body")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN)
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: hi, I did try this code, but it seems the data are append even when using file_put_contents

Comment: Then there was an error in your implementation.  Your outcome is not the default behavior of `file_put_contents()`.  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: Better check that this isn't a misunderstanding with your database table results.  Remove the file write from the task to debug.  `var_export($dbh->query("SELECT bodyipaddress FROM email_body")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN));`

Comment: for update, I manage by using your code, but was it possible if wanted to  include `$padded_text    = str_replace(',',"\n", $bodyipaddress);
$white_space    =  PHP_EOL . str_replace(' ', '', $padded_text);` inside my code, because i don't want to display original formatting in database

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the challenge that you are trying to overcome.  Can you show me some of the troublesome text in a 3v4l.org demo?  You can wrap additional string manipulating functions around the `implode()` call.  `str_replace()` can be used before or after the `implode()` call because it will happily modify a string or an array of strings.  Instead of using `\n`, try to use `PHP_EOL` throughout for consistency.  If you want to remove comma-space substrings, remove them in one action `str_replace(', ', PHP_EOL, implode(...))`.

Comment: kindly referred  this link, details for my problem   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66794055/create-a-text-file-with-formatting

Answer (score 2):

Use PHP_EOL which outputs \r\n or \n .
OR
fwrite($myfile, $bodyipaddress . "\n");

Answer (score 0):

I would ideally do this way, apart from the adding PHP_EOL, moved fopen and fclose outside the foreach loop, since there is no need to open and close the file for every iteration.

```
$sql = "SELECT bodyipaddress from email_body";
$query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$cnt=1;
if($query->rowCount() > 0)
{
     // create a txt file outside the foreach
    $myfile      = fopen("file.txt", "a");
    foreach ($results as $result)   
    {
        $bodyipaddress       = $result->bodyipaddress;
        
        //add a new line 
        $padded_text .= PHP_EOL . str_pad($bodyipaddress, 0, '', STR_PAD_RIGHT);
        fwrite($myfile, $bodyipaddress);
                                        
        $cnt=$cnt+1; 
    }
 fclose($myfile);
}
```